# OkHttp3 - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

In my app I use retrofit2(2.9.0) with OkHttp3(3.14.4). I want to add tls client certificate to all of my requests to some api. I've got the certificate in a `.p12` file. I read the file, loaded into X509Certificate class then I used the `.addTrustedCertificate(certificate)` method. The certificate is correct I tried it using curl. Unfortunately when I run the code I get an exception.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:641)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.reactor.ExecuteSinkConsumer.accept(ExecuteSinkConsumer.java:39)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.reactor.ExecuteSinkConsumer.accept(ExecuteSinkConsumer.java:24)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.subscribe(FluxCreate.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8143)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.reactor.BodyFlux.subscribe(BodyFlux.java:36)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FluxSubscribeOn.java:194)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:625)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 53 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my code looks like this

```
val fileName = "certyficate.p12"
val file = File(fileName)
val inputStream = file.inputStream()
val p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12")
val password = "password"
p12.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray())
val alias = p12.aliases().nextElement()
val certificate = p12.getCertificate(alias) as X509Certificate
val ob = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
val hostname = "https://myapi.com"
val timeout = 5L
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .apply {
            addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            })
    }
    .apply {
            val clientCertificate = HandshakeCertificates
                .Builder()
                .addTrustedCertificate(certificate)
                .build()
            sslSocketFactory(clientCertificate.sslSocketFactory(), clientCertificate.trustManager())
    }
    .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(hostname)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(
        io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.io()
    ))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(ReactorCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.newElastic(
        MyApi::class.java.name
    )))
    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(ob))
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()

val p = retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)
val res = p.doRequest().block()
println(res)
```

What's a possible reason? how to correctly use client certificates when using OkHttp3 ?

EDIT after I added `.addPlatformTrustedCertificates()` I get

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:180)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.reactor.ExecuteSinkConsumer.accept(ExecuteSinkConsumer.java:39)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.reactor.ExecuteSinkConsumer.accept(ExecuteSinkConsumer.java:24)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.subscribe(FluxCreate.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8143)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.reactor.BodyFlux.subscribe(BodyFlux.java:36)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FluxSubscribeOn.java:194)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I run with `javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and found in my logs

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|12|my.app.MyApi-2|2021-03-03 14:00:09.656 CET|CertificateMessage.java:290|No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|12|my.app.MyApi-2|2021-03-03 14:00:09.656 CET|CertificateMessage.java:321|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)
```

also my build.gradle

```
compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'retrofit', version: '2.9.0'
compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'converter-jackson', version: '2.9.0'
compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'adapter-rxjava2', version: '2.9.0'
compile group: 'com.jakewharton.retrofit', name: 'retrofit2-reactor-adapter', version: '2.1.0'
compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp-tls', version: '3.14.4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 val p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12").apply {
        load(inputStream, password)
    }
    val clientCert = p12.getCertificateChain(alias)[0] as X509Certificate
    val rootCert = p12.getCertificateChain(alias)[1] as X509Certificate
    val clientPrivateKey = p12.getKey(alias, password) as PrivateKey
    val clientTLSCredentials = HeldCertificate(KeyPair(clientCert.publicKey, clientPrivateKey), clientCert)
    val clientTlsHandShake = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
        .heldCertificate(clientTLSCredentials, rootCert)
        .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
        .build()
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .sslSocketFactory(clientTlsHandShake.sslSocketFactory(), clientTlsHandShake.trustManager())
        .build()
```

Comment: This was it for me. I've been working through the docs for a week now and haven't gotten past the error OP had.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working, see for an example https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/083315a473d8b2fc972a70449272b296683ac38c/android-test/src/androidTest/java/okhttp/android/test/letsencrypt/LetsEncryptClientTest.kt

```
      val handshakeCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
        .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
        .addTrustedCertificate(cert)
        .build()

      clientBuilder
        .sslSocketFactory(handshakeCertificates.sslSocketFactory(),
          handshakeCertificates.trustManager)
```

You should can look at the certificate chain in SunCertPathBuilderException in a debugger.

> This is a subclass of the generic CertPathBuilderException. It contains an adjacency list with information regarding the unsuccessful paths that the SunCertPathBuilder tried.

Ultimately you may need to enable SSL debugging in JSSE to see why it is failing.

Comment: It doesn't work even though I added `.addPlatformTrustedCertificates()`. Now I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`. I added full stacktrace to the original post. I tried to connect using python and there was no problem. Could it mean there's something wrong with my java installation ?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this working using Clyde Barrow's solution. Here is my pure Java solution (not much different than Clyde's). This is using a client certificate signed by Entrust and an intermediate certificate.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("myKeyStore.jks")), "mypassword".toCharArray());

Certificate[] certificates = keyStore.getCertificateChain("myalias");
X509Certificate clientCertificate = (X509Certificate) certificates[0];
X509Certificate intermediateCertificate = (X509Certificate) certificates[1];
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("myalias", "mypassword".toCharArray());
PublicKey publicKey = clientCertificate.getPublicKey();
KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
HeldCertificate heldCertificate = new HeldCertificate(keyPair, clientCertificate);

HandshakeCertificates.Builder builder =
    new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
        .heldCertificate(heldCertificate, intermediateCertificate)
        .addPlatformTrustedCertificates();

HandshakeCertificates handshakeCertificates = builder.build();

OkHttpClient okClient =
    new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .sslSocketFactory(handshakeCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), handshakeCertificates.trustManager())
        .build();
```